# WebSocket in browser with true back-pressure

Tags: websocket, browser, webassembly, backpressure

I learned the hard way that the browsers' [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) [does not support back-pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029590/6094756). Is there a way to work around this limitation without having to manually implement control flow on the application layer protocol? Would it for example be possible to implement a full WebSocket client in WASM, instead of having to proxy everything through the browser's API?

Answer (score 0):

Back-pressure: no changes to the protocol that are addressing this issue are published to this time.

WebAssembly: there is no access to the WebSocket API (or any other) at this time from a pure WebAssembly module. You will have to use JavaScript in one way or another.